# Android TV Gridview dpad composed items

Tags: android

I'm sorry if this question has been answered before. Honestly, I have searched this issue a lot and although there are similar cases, none of them helped me.

I am developing an Android Application for a TV. I have created a GridView because I want to show some thumbnails of pictures and videos. Each item in the gridview has a picture and a text info below.

The problem is that I can't get the dpad to work properly. If I set android:focusable="true" in the items, I can navigate through the GridView, but I can't display the image/video after pressing enter or using the mouse (no call to "onItemClick()"). If I do not set android:focusable="true", I can't navigate through the GridView (maybe cuz I do not see it) and also I can't press enter and see the image/video, but I do can click with the mouse the item and see the image/video.

What can I do to make the dpad work properly?

Thank you very much in advance. I have been struggling with this since a big while, I would sincerely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the exact same problem yesterday. What you need to do is add an onKeyListener to the GridView and inside the onKey function handle the key presses. I'll share what I did with it so that you can build on it.

```
gridView.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER){
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "CENTER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                if(gridView.getSelectedItemPosition() == -1){
                    if(gridView.getCount() > 0)
                        gridView.setSelection(0);
                    else
                        return false;
                }
                CURRENT_VIDEO_NUM = gridView.getSelectedItemPosition();
            }
            else{
                switch(keyCode){
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_RIGHT:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "RIGHT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(event.getAction() == 0){
                            try {
                                if (gridView.getSelectedItemPosition() < gridViewAdapter.getCount() - 1) {
                                    gridView.setSelection(gridView.getSelectedItemPosition() + 1);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                gridView.setSelection(gridViewAdapter.getCount() - 1);
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "LEFT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        if(event.getAction() == 0){
                            try {
                                if (gridView.getSelectedItemPosition() > 0) {
                                    gridView.setSelection(gridView.getSelectedItemPosition() - 1);
                                    return true;
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                gridView.setSelection(0);
                                return true;
                            }
                        }
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_UP:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ELSE" + keyCode, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;

                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now let me explain whats happening here.
1) I check if the center button is pressed, if thats the case, I'll perform the action that is to be performed when an item is clicked.
2) If RIGHT button is pressed, the selection is moved to right and the same for the left one.
3) UP and DOWN are a little less trivial. Since I was just building a demo, I didn't spend time on it. Won't be a problem though, just increment/decrement the total number of columns of the grid view keeping in mind the max/min of the items.

Try building on it and if you face any issue, do let me know.